# Weird characters and deficiency of the attribute. Python

Tags: python, attributes, character

I've created a function and got stuck on it.

Meaning of the function:

1. User types in a file, number and own name.
2. Program writes the name at the end of the file 'number' times.
3. And just prints out contents of the file.

What's the problem?

1. There are strange characters and a big space under it when program reads the file.

Like this: ਍圀漀爀氀搀眀椀搀攀㬀 ㈀　　㐀 ⴀ 瀀爀攀猀攀渀琀ഀഀ (and then there is a huge space for 10-15 lines in Powershell)

2. Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'.

   ```
   def filemania():

       print "Great! This way is called \"Filemania\""

       file_name = raw_input("Type in any text file> ")
       enter_1 = int(raw_input("Enter an integer> "))
       enter_2 = raw_input("Enter your name> ")

       print "Now your name will apear in the file %d times at the end" % enter_1

       open_file = open(file_name, 'a+')
       listok = []

       while len(listok) < enter_1:
           open_file.write(enter_2 + " ")
           listok.append(enter_2) 

       print "Contains of the file:"
       read_file = open_file.read()
       print read_file
       file_name.close()

   filemania()
   ```

I think the problem is somewhere here:

open_file = open(file_name, 'a+')

Does somebody know how to solve these problems?

Comment: How would a string have a close method?  `file_name = raw_input("Type in any text file> ")` your file objects are `read_file` and  `open_file` the latter  you never close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you  set `file_name = raw_input("Type in any text file> ")` so you are trying to close a string with  `file_name.close()`:

When you write to `open_file` you move the pointer to the end of the file because you are appending so  `read_file = open_file.read()` is not going to do what you think.

You will need to seek to the start of the file again to print the content, `open_file.seek(0)`.

```
def filemania():
    print "Great! This way is called \"Filemania\""
    file_name = raw_input("Type in any text file> ")
    enter_1 = int(raw_input("Enter an integer> "))
    enter_2 = raw_input("Enter your name> ")

    print "Now your name will apear in the file %d times at the end" % enter_1

    # with automatically closes your files
    with open(file_name, 'a+') as open_file:
        listok = []
        # use range      
        for _ in range(enter_1):
            open_file.write(enter_2 + " ")
            listok.append(enter_2)
        print "Contains of the file:"
        # move pointer to start of the file again
        open_file.seek(0) 
        read_file = open_file.read()
        print read_file

filemania()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your variant of the code works. But i'm new in Python and i haven't known yet about with...as... .

Comment: Is it possible to close the file somehow with argv or *args (change the string to an argument)?

Comment: @NikitaShub, change which string to an argument?

Comment: I mean changing file_name. As i've understood it's a string. Maybe there is a way to make file_name as an argument? Ex. from sys import argv, script, file_name = argv

Comment: yes, if you want to run it taking the filename from the command line use argv

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, 
the last question: if i want to do it, is it possible to type in arguments somewhere in the middle of the code? As i know argv allows to type in arguments only at the beginning of the program in the Terminal.

Comment: If you want to take arguments after you run the code use raw_input

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, i agree. But there is a problem if i want to type in a file as in my code above. I want to type in file after running the code and work with it.

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, i want to type in a file in the middle of the code. As i unterstood from your comment on my question that it is impossible to type in a file in the middle of the code using raw_input(), because raw_input() returns a string. How can i type in a file to work with it later without raw_input()? sys.argv won't help because i needn't to type in a file before running a code.

Comment: Pass the filename to raw_input and open it, what will not work doing that?

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, as i understood it will be impossible to use close method this way.

Comment: That is what `with` is for

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, ok, sorry to trouble you. Now i've unterstood, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For your second error, you are trying to close `file_name`, which is the raw input string. You mean to close `open_file`

Try that and report back.

Comment: The result is the same.